# Which one of these two (Always/Never) data usage settings restrict background data in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

Please help me, I am not understanding which one of these two option actually going to **restrict** background data in windows 10

[image: ....see the image]

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.  Please edit your question and explain in enough detail what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: If you always restrict your food intake, you may not grow fat. If you never restrict your food intake, you could grow fat.

Comment: As**e ****** *** 8*

Answer (score 0):

Setting your connection to "Metered" and choosing "Always" from your example picture will give you the most of what Windows 10 has control over.

Note; some apps have their own settings for background data usage. These may not be controllable via the settings options in Windows 10.  You will need to look at the app itself to modify those settings.  Some also may not be able to be modified.

Hope this info helps.